# Install crt certificate on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, certificates

I have a .crt certificate and I've tried installing it in .local/share/ca-certificates (I've created this last folder because It didn't exist) and put my ca.crt into it , then I executed this command :

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

And received this output :

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
```

As I see 0 added 0 removed I think that the .crt didn't installed correctly . How should I install this .crt certificates ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your `.crt` file in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.
Please refer to `man update-ca-certificates`for detailed information.